Continuity of Inverse Laplace transform on suitable subspaces
I came across of the following relation. Taking a sum of exponentials (SOE) $E(x)=\sum_{j=1}^N b_j e^{\gamma_j x}$, with $b_j\in \mathbb C$ and $\gamma_j \in \mathbb C_-$  (left part of the complex plane. Then the Laplace transform creates the relation
$$\mathcal L_E(s)=\sum_{j=1}^N b_j\int_0^\infty e^{\gamma_jx}e^{-sx}dx=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{b_j}{s-\gamma_j}=r(s).$$
Thus, the Laplace transform gives us a natural transformation between SOE's and sums of pols (SOP). It is well known, that the Laplace transform $\mathcal L\colon L^2(0,\infty)\to L^2(0,\infty) $ is continuous with upper bound $\sqrt \pi$. Also it is known that the inverse Laplace transform is not continuous. I am interested in the (dis)continuity of the inverse Laplace transform regarded from $SOP\to SOE$, while  $SOP$ denotes the set of sums of pols with pols lying on the left part of the complex plane. And similarly with $SOE$ and frequencies with negative real part. Both spaces can be equipped with $L^2$ norm on $(0,\infty)$, forming a pre-Hilbert space.
My general feeling is, that the inverse transform should be continuous between those two spaces. If we take a sequence of SOP's $r_n$ convergece to $0$, then either the weights go to zero, the pols go to infinit or some parameters converge to one another. All those condition cause also a SOE to converge to 0. At least this is what I could think of.
Computing the norm of a SOP
$$||r||_2^2= \sum_{k,j=1}^N b_j\overline{b}_k \frac{\log(-\gamma_j)-\log(-\overline \gamma_k)}{\gamma_j-\overline \gamma_k},$$
while using branch cut at $\mathbb R_+$. Computing the norm of exponential sums
$$||E||_2^2=\sum_{j,k=1}^N b_j\overline b_k \frac {-1} {\gamma_j +\overline \gamma_k}.$$
Although, both norms look very similar I can not find any estimate of the form
$$||E||_2^2\leq C||r||_2^2.$$
Do you have any suggestions to prove or disprove the continuity? Or maybe some literature where to look up? I would be very greatful.
